# Changing size of axis labels in hexbin plot

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

Is there a way to change the font size of axis labels when plotting hexbin data?

```
library(hexbin)
myData <- hexbin(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)) 
myPlot <- plot(myData, xlab = "Variable 1", ylab = "Variable 2")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Variable 1/2 or the tick labels or both?

Comment: Editing the tick labels too would be great! This is what I actually mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the labels and add them separately with grid commands. It may take some trial and error to position them exactly where you want them:

```
library(grid)
myPlot <- plot(myData, xlab="", ylab="", lcex=.75)
grid.text("Variable 1", .45, .1, gp=gpar(fontsize=12))
grid.text("Variable 2", .05, .5, rot=90, gp=gpar(fontsize=12))
```

[image: Hexbin Plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, which exactly does what I have asked for. To be honest, I had hoped for a way using editing of `grobs` because I am also thinking about adjusting/modifying the font size of the numbers along the axes.

Comment: You can do this using `grid.ls()` to get the names of the grobs and then using  `gpar` to change the fontsize: `grid.edit("GRID.text.45", gp=gpar(fontsize=12))`.

Comment: @dcarlson: thanks for your answer, which already helped me. Unfortunately, I can't quite get your suggestion about axis *annotation* fontsizes to work, so I posted [a followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59396848/452096). Perhaps you would be interested in answering it?