# Changing the fontsize of axis annotations in a hexbinplot

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I would like to increase the font size of axis annotations in a hexbinplot.

```
library(hexbin)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
hb <- hexbin(x=df$x, df$y)
myPlot <- plot(hb, xlab="", ylab="", legend=FALSE)
```

[image: hexbinplot]

I would like the -3, ..., 2 and the -2, ..., 3 on the axes to be larger.

[This earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48651010/452096) already helped me with axis *labels*, but [the suggestion about how to change the *annotations*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651010/changing-size-of-axis-labels-in-hexbin-plot#comment84416922_48651853) ("use `grid.ls()`" - how?) is a little too cryptic for me. I am more fluent in base graphics than in lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
library(grid)
myPlot <- plot(hb, xlab="", ylab="", legend=FALSE)
grid.ls()
# GRID.rect.250
# GRID.xaxis.251
# GRID.yaxis.252
# GRID.polygon.253
grid.edit("GRID.xaxis.251", gp=gpar(fontsize=20))
grid.edit("GRID.yaxis.252", gp=gpar(fontsize=20))
```

The `grid.ls()` function shows the parts of the graph. The axis labels are `GRID.xaxis.251` and `GRID.yaxis.252`. The name labels should be the same but the numbers will be different so you will have to modify the `grid.edit()` lines to match the output from `grid.ls()`.

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot! Since I need this in a little script, I used `grep("axis",grid.ls(print=FALSE)$name,value=TRUE)` to get those pesky names.